# Pattern string with four apostrophes

Tags: c#, regex, specflow

I would like to extract "Child 1" and "Parent 1" (without the apostrophes) from string

```
there is a child object with name "Child 1" under parent "Parent 1" in the tree
```

The patter string

```
there is a child object with name "([\w\s^"]+)" under parent "([\w\s^"]+)" in the tree
```

does not seem to be correct as it matches also the whole string that I do not want.

I have tested it with http://www.myregextester.com/index.php.

I need this to write a step for SpecFlow in C#.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, it seems that the problem is caused by the existence of another regex pattern string for one of my other SpecFlow step definition: `there is a child object with name "([\w\s^"]+)" in the tree` that is applied for: `there is a child object with name "Child 1" in the tree` If I comment this step definition out, the original string is understood by SpecFlow, but if both steps are present, only the this one is recognized, the other with four apostrophes is not.

Comment: The convention of having SpecFlow parameters within apostrophes makes it easy for a reader and a maintainer of the tests to see what is being used input. Removing apostrophes will make it harder to easily see what are SpecFlow parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex pattern: `([\w\s^"]+)` will match strings with quotes in.

I'm not certain why this effect happens.  It seems as if mixing inclusive character sets and exclusive ones doesn't work.  I'd be interested if anyone has any more knowledge on that point.

Really you want `([^"]+)`, I.E.

```
there is a child object with name "([^"]+)" under parent "([^"]+)" in the tree
```

for one of your steps and

```
there is a child object with name "([^"]+)" in the tree
```

for the other.

Answer (score 0):

To me it feels cleaner to not use Regex for this. If you loosen your requirement a tiny bit and only try a regular expression.. it will match text between a closing quote and an opening one.

Perhaps you would get better results doing it manually?

```
    string[] extractBetweenQuotes(string str)
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        int firstQuote = 0;
        firstQuote = str.IndexOf("\"");

        while (firstQuote > -1)
        {
            int secondQuote = str.IndexOf("\"", firstQuote + 1);
            if (secondQuote > -1)
            {
                list.Add(str.Substring(firstQuote + 1, secondQuote - (firstQuote + 1)));
                firstQuote = str.IndexOf("\"", secondQuote + 1);
                continue;
            }

            firstQuote = str.IndexOf("\"", firstQuote + 1);
        }

        return list.ToArray();
    }
```

Usage:

```
string str = "there is a child object with name \"Child 1\" under parent \"Parent 1\" in the tree";

string[] parts = extractBetweenQuotes(str); // Child 1 and Parent 1 (no quotes)
```

Comment: Many thanks, Simon, for your input. I don't know if SpecFlow allows us to implement custom parsers, however.

Answer (score 0):

So your current pattern is doing;

```
( #Start group
  [ #start choice of 
    \w # word character
    \s #whitespace 
    ^" #not a speechmark
  ] # end choice 
  + # at least one of the choices
) # end group
```

And because Regex is greedy by default, it can keep matching word characters or spaces to the end of the line.

I would instead suggest you just use

```
[^"]+ #keep going until you hit a speechmark
```

And in specflow this looks like

```
[Given("there is a child object with name \"[^\"]+\" under parent \"[^\"]+\" in the tree")]
```